# How to use Forge API with other Storage (Azure, S3, ...)

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am working with Forge API (Management API, Model Derivative API, Automation API, Forge Viewer).
I want to store my files (mostly revit files) on Azure Storage instead of on OSS. But I have problem with Model Derivative API. I can't get the URN from the files uploaded to Azure.

Do I have to use OSS to get the URN?
Thanks a lot.

I have tried uploading files to both Azure Storage and OSS simultaneously, but the speed is quite slow, and affects performance.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot translate the file without uploading it to OSS. You can delete it from OSS after translating and still view it in Viewer.